# Ubuntu 16.10 Files closes straight after opening

Tags: nautilus, 16.10

Since upgrading from 16.04 to 16.10, when I click the 'Files' icon in the launcher it opens as usual but immediately closes again. I can't browse the filesystem which is a bit of a nuisance. Can I re-install the Files app?

Running `nautilus` from terminal, it opens up then closes again leaving this in the terminal window:

```
$ sudo nautilus
[sudo] password for mike: 

(nautilus:8973): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 2015.10.28
**
ERROR:nautilus-canvas-container.c:6032:finish_adding_new_icons: assertion failed: (!container->details->auto_layout)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This is the contents of `/var/log`:

```
total 6884
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root    1845 Nov 16 18:36 alternatives.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root   31487 Oct 28 19:01 alternatives.log.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root     681 Sep 29 19:32 alternatives.log.2.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root     500 Sep  1 17:17 alternatives.log.3.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root    4614 Jul 21 15:31 alternatives.log.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root              adm     2179 Nov 16 19:08 apport.log
-rw-r----- 1 root              adm     2535 Nov 16 01:00 apport.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 root              adm      387 Nov 15 15:58 apport.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root              adm      233 Nov 14 19:49 apport.log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root              adm      232 Nov 13 15:09 apport.log.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root              adm      229 Nov 12 16:36 apport.log.5.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root              adm      301 Nov 11 20:14 apport.log.6.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root              adm      233 Nov 10 18:57 apport.log.7.gz
drwxr-xr-x 2 root              root    4096 Nov 16 18:36 apt
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm    35106 Nov 16 19:17 auth.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm    28808 Nov 13 15:08 auth.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm     4419 Nov  7 16:09 auth.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm     4737 Oct 30 18:00 auth.log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm     4933 Oct 23 16:55 auth.log.4.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root    4440 Oct 20 19:34 boot.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root   57457 Apr 20  2016 bootstrap.log
-rw------- 1 root              utmp       0 Nov  1 18:27 btmp
-rw------- 1 root              utmp       0 Oct  1 17:00 btmp.1
drwxr-xr-x 2 root              root    4096 Nov 16 17:36 cups
drwxr-xr-x 2 root              root    4096 Oct 23 17:13 dist-upgrade
-rw-r----- 1 root              adm       31 Apr 20  2016 dmesg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root  135150 Nov 16 18:36 dpkg.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root 1965153 Oct 28 20:29 dpkg.log.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root   16088 Sep 29 19:32 dpkg.log.2.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root   15937 Sep  1 17:17 dpkg.log.3.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root  157812 Jul 31 17:55 dpkg.log.4.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root   32032 Oct 23 18:20 faillog
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root    4562 Oct 23 18:29 fontconfig.log
drwxr-xr-x 2 root              root    4096 Apr 20  2016 fsck
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root    1988 Nov 16 17:30 gpu-manager.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root     288 Jul  4 22:12 gufw.log
drwxr-xr-x 3 root              root    4096 Jul  2 22:36 installer
drwx------ 2 root              root    4096 Nov 15 15:59 iptraf
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm   821402 Nov 16 19:26 kern.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm   944399 Nov 13 15:11 kern.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm   292954 Nov  7 16:10 kern.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm   234709 Oct 30 18:04 kern.log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm   242290 Oct 23 16:54 kern.log.4.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root              utmp  292292 Oct 23 18:20 lastlog
drwxr-xr-x 2 root              root    4096 Nov 16 17:36 lightdm
-rw-r----- 1 root              root  305760 Jul  4 21:14 lynis.log
-rw-r----- 1 root              root   82228 Jul  4 21:14 lynis-report.dat
drwx------ 2 speech-dispatcher root    4096 Feb 18  2016 speech-dispatcher
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm    41328 Nov 16 19:41 syslog
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm   752716 Nov 16 17:36 syslog.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm    43507 Nov 15 15:59 syslog.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm    46339 Nov 14 19:50 syslog.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm    46572 Nov 13 15:11 syslog.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm    39367 Nov 12 16:38 syslog.5.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm    63941 Nov 11 20:16 syslog.6.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm    53450 Nov 10 19:00 syslog.7.gz
drwxr-s--- 2 debian-tor        adm     4096 Nov 16 17:36 tor
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm        0 Jul 10 17:14 ufw.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm     5134 Jul  4 22:10 ufw.log.1
drwxr-x--- 2 root              adm     4096 Nov  1 18:27 unattended-upgrades
drwxr-xr-x 2 root              root    4096 Feb 29  2016 upstart
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root              utmp   50688 Nov 16 17:34 wtmp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root              utmp  104064 Nov  1 18:23 wtmp.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root   61639 Nov 16 17:35 Xorg.0.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root   61643 Nov 15 20:11 Xorg.0.log.old
```

This is the output after running `nautilus` without `sudo`:

```
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 2015.10.28

(nautilus:8659): NA-core-WARNING **: na_settings_content_load_keys: /home/mike/.config/nautilus-actions/nautilus-actions.conf (2) Permission denied
**
ERROR:nautilus-canvas-container.c:6032:finish_adding_new_icons: assertion failed: (!container->details->auto_layout)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `nautilus`?

Comment: Also, you really shouldn't run graphical applications such as `nautilus` as root (`sudo`). It can mess up file permissions etc. If you are to run it as root with `sudo`, then please run it as follows: `sudo -H nautilus`. As this will hopefully prevent such permissions issues. Although I would still advise against running Nautilus as root.

Comment: This sounds like a bug though which is causing it to crash. Please provide the output of `ls -l /var/log`.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: Even better than `sudo -H <GRAPHICAL_APPLICATION>` would be `gksudo <GRAPHICAL_APPLICATION>` (or `gksu` – they're the same).

Comment: Could you please run `nautilus` *without* `sudo` in a terminal and include the output in your question?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Dropbox? It seems that, with your upgrade, something with Dropbox isn't working correctly. That might be causing the trouble.

Comment: Looks like `sudo nautilus` might have give ownership over some of your Nautilus configuration files to the root user which causes problems now. Could you please reset the ownership over all user configuration files (`sudo chown -R "$USER:" ~/.config ~/.local`) and try again? Does the output of `nautilus` on the terminal change?

Answer (score 12):

A quick fix that seems to work for many is just to remove your current nautilus configuration: `rm -rf ~/.config/nautilus`

Comment: In cases like this, it's mostly advisable not to just delete the files in question, but to rename it. That way, you can get them back if the problem turns out to be somewhere else, or you can extract info from them for the new config. So instead of `rm`, I'd use something like `mv ~/.config/nautilus ~/.config/nautilus-old`.

Comment: @Henning Kockerbeck I've just tried your suggestion and is is working!